# Default value for SO_RCVTIMEO option on Solaris

Tags: networking, solaris, tcp, socket

Is there any way to find out what is the default value set for option SO_RCVTIMEO on Solaris 10?

If there is a way to find out how would one go about changing it?

P.S.  I am aware of ability of using `getsockopt` after creation to see what the setting is, but I am looking for a way of setting this globally and not individually.

Comment: Is `grep -n SO_RCVTIMEO /usr/include/sys/socket.h` what are you looking for?

Comment: @dchirikov That's not a value of the timeout.

Comment: Meddling with the finely tuned default timeouts for TCP is like the rules of program optimization: "Don't do it. Rule for experts: Don't do it (yet)". You have to have an absolutely clear reason do do this, and probably never on Intenrnet-facing links.

Comment: @vonbrand If they were finely tuned for what this machine does the question wouldn't come up. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `getsockopt()` or `setsockopt()` return an error with that option? Is `SO_RCVTIMEO` listed on your `setsockopt` man page? It's not on mine, and it's not supported up to and including Solaris 10 AFAIK. (I don't have a Solaris 11 to hand to check its status there, Google tells me it was added to OpenSolaris, so there's good chance.)

In general, TCP defaults and tuning parameters can be inspected or configured using `ndd`:

```
$ /usr/sbin/ndd -get /dev/tcp \? | fgrep time
tcp_time_wait_interval        (read and write)
tcp_co_timer_interval         (read and write)
tcp_push_timer_interval       (read and write)
tcp_close_wait_interval(obsoleted- use tcp_time_wait_interval) (no read or write)

$ /usr/sbin/ndd -get /dev/tcp  tcp_time_wait_interval
60000
```